# Python pytest pytest_exception_interact customize exception information from VCR.py exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

## Context

I have started using [`pytest-vcr`](https://pytest-vcr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is a [`pytest`](https://doc.pytest.org/) plugin wrapping [`VCR.py`](https://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) which I have documented in [this blog post on Advanced Python Testing](https://joshpeak.net/posts/2019-06-18-Advanced-python-testing.html#be-kind-and-rewind).

It records all HTTP traffic to `cassettes/*.yml` files on the first test run to save snapshots. Similar to [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) snapshot testing for web components.

On subsequent test runs, if a request is malformed, it won't find a match and throws an exception saying that *recording new requests is forbidden* and it did not find an existing recording.

## Question

`VCR.py` raises a `CannotOverwriteExistingCassetteException` which is not particularly informative as to why it didn't match.

> How do I leverage pytest [`pytest_exception_interact`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact) hooks to replace this exception with a more informative one leveraging fixture information?

I dove into my `site-packages` where `VCR.py` is `pip installed` and rewrote how I want it to handle the exception. I just need to know how to get this `pytest_exception_interact` hook to work correctly to access the fixtures from that test node (before it gets cleaned up) and raise a different exception.

## Example

Lets get the dependencies.

```sh
$ pip install pytest pytest-vcr requests
```

**test_example.py:**

```py
import pytest
import requests

@pytest.mark.vcr
def test_example():
    r = requests.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
    assert r.status_code == 200
```

```sh
$ pytest test_example.py --vcr-record=once
...
test_example.py::test_example PASSED 
...
$ ls cassettes/
cassettes/test_example.yml
$ head cassettes/test_example.yml
interactions:
- request:
    uri: https://wwwstackoverflow.com
    body: null
    headers:
        Accept:
        - '*/*'
$ pytest test_example.py --vcr-record=none
...
test_example.py::test_example PASSED 
...
```

Now change the URI in the test to "https://www.google.com":

**test_example.py:**

```py
import pytest
import requests

@pytest.mark.vcr
def test_example():
    r = requests.get("https://www.google.com")
    assert r.status_code == 200
```

And run the test again to detect the regression:

```sh
$ pytest test_example.py --vcr-record=none
E               vcr.errors.CannotOverwriteExistingCassetteException: No match for the request (<Request (GET) https://www.google.com/>)
...
```

I can add a `conftest.py` file to the root of my test structure to create a *local plugin*, and I can verify that I can intercept the exception and inject my own using:

**conftest.py**

```py
import pytest
from vcr.errors import CannotOverwriteExistingCassetteException
from vcr.config import VCR
from vcr.cassette import Cassette

class RequestNotFoundCassetteException(CannotOverwriteExistingCassetteException):
    ...

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _vcr_marker(request):
    marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("vcr")
    if marker:
        cassette = request.getfixturevalue("vcr_cassette")
        vcr = request.getfixturevalue("vcr")
        request.node.__vcr_fixtures = dict(vcr_cassette=cassette, vcr=vcr)
    yield


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_exception_interact(node, call, report):
    excinfo = call.excinfo
    if report.when == "call" and isinstance(excinfo.value, CannotOverwriteExistingCassetteException):
        # Safely check for fixture pass through on this node
        cassette = None
        vcr = None
        if hasattr(node, "__vcr_fixtures"):
            for fixture_name, fx in node.__vcr_fixtures.items():
                vcr = fx if isinstance(fx, VCR)
                cassette = fx if isinstance(fx, Cassette)

        # If we have the extra fixture context available...
        if cassette and vcr:
            match_properties = [f.__name__ for f in cassette._match_on]
            cassette_reqs = cassette.requests
            #  filtered_req = cassette.filter_request(vcr._vcr_request)
            #  this_req, req_str = __format_near_match(filtered_req, cassette_reqs, match_properties)

            # Raise and catch a new excpetion FROM existing one to keep the traceback
            # https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752607/622276
            # https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions
            try:
                raise RequestNotFoundCassetteException(
                    f"\nMatching Properties: {match_properties}\n" f"Cassette Requests: {cassette_reqs}\n"
                ) from excinfo.value
            except RequestNotFoundCassetteException as e:
                excinfo._excinfo = (type(e), e)
                report.longrepr = node.repr_failure(excinfo)
```

This is the part where the documentation on the internet gets pretty thin.

> How do I access the [`vcr_cassette`](https://pytest-vcr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#vcr) fixture and return a different exception?

What I want to do is get the `filtered_request` that was attempting to be requested and the list of `cassette_requests` and using the [Python difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) standard library produce deltas against the information that diverged.

## PyTest Code Spelunking

The internals of running a single test with pytest triggers `pytest_runtest_protocol` which effectively runs the following three `call_and_report` calls to get a collection of reports.

[**src/_pytest/runner.py:L77-L94**](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/5976f36240c2990b3f2b0dca44e8b5435a1040dc/src/_pytest/runner.py#L77-L94)

```py
def runtestprotocol(item, log=True, nextitem=None):
    # Abbreviated
    reports = []
    reports.append(call_and_report(item, "setup", log))
    reports.append(call_and_report(item, "call", log))
    reports.append(call_and_report(item, "teardown", log))
    return reports
```

So I'm after modifying the report at the *call* stage... but still no clue how I get access to the fixture information.

[**src/_pytest/runner.py:L166-L174**](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/5976f36240c2990b3f2b0dca44e8b5435a1040dc/src/_pytest/runner.py#L173)

```py
def call_and_report(item, when, log=True, **kwds):
    call = call_runtest_hook(item, when, **kwds)
    hook = item.ihook
    report = hook.pytest_runtest_makereport(item=item, call=call)
    if log:
        hook.pytest_runtest_logreport(report=report)
    if check_interactive_exception(call, report):
        hook.pytest_exception_interact(node=item, call=call, report=report)
    return report
```

It looks like there are some helper methods for generating a new ExceptionRepresentation so I updated the **conftest.py** example.

[**src/_pytest/reports.py:L361**](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/5976f36240c2990b3f2b0dca44e8b5435a1040dc/src/_pytest/reports.py#L361)

```py
longrepr = item.repr_failure(excinfo)
```

**UPDATE #1 2019-06-26**: Thanks to [some pointers from @hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745834/python-pytest-pytest-exception-interact-customize-exception-information-from-vcr#comment100063551_56745834) in the comments I updated my **conftest.py**.

- *Correctly* re-raising the exception using the [`raise ... from ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752607/622276) form.
- Override the `_vcr_marker` to attach the `vcr` and `vcr_cassette` fixtures to the `request.node` which represent that individual test item.
- **Remaining**: Get access to the intercepted request from the patched VCRConnection...

**UPDATE #2 2019-06-26**

It would seem impossible to get at the VCRHTTPConnections that were patched in creating the cassette context manager. I have opened up the following pull request to pass as arguments when the exception is thrown, to then catch and handle arbitrarily down stream.

https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy/pull/445

## Related

Related questions that are informative but still don't answer this question.

- [Customizing error message for specific exceptions in pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521111/customizing-error-message-for-specific-exceptions-in-pytest)

Comment: I wish all questions on SO were like this.

Comment: Regarding your actual question: you can passthrough the fixture values by attaching them to a global object, usually I use the `config` for this. E.g. redefine `vcr` fixture with the body `request.config._vcr = vcr; return vcr` and access it via `node.session.config._vcr` in the hook. I can describe it in an answer with a working example if you need it.

Comment: Regarding the exception modification: you are on the right track with the `pytest_exception_interact` hook; however, I would not modify the existing `ExceptionInfo` object and create a new one instead. What I don't like in your approach is that the exchanged exception won't match the traceback anymore; I would probably raise a new exception of your own type from the current one in the hook (`raise MyEx('text') from call.excinfo.value`), catch it and inject new excinfo via e.g. `call.excinfo = ExceptionInfo.from_current()`, so at least you preserve the original traceback.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling! I'll give that a try tomorrow and circle back. I've managed to intercept the exception and replace it with a new one. This might be the trick to getting the fixture context I need for the new detailed exception. Oh and good tip on raising a new Exception. I didn't like the replacement anyhow.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the raising and immediate catch is a good approach either, I can imagine it will look ugly in code. I'll think about something better and report back.

Comment: @hoefling the re-raising and appending the fixtures to the node worked thank you! I updated the conftest.py example in the question. Unfortunately I still need access to the patched VCRConnection Request that triggered it all. But progress is appreciated. More spelunking!

Comment: Hmm, the access to `VCRConnection` looks tricky - have you thought about monkeypatching it yourself? Subclass, override the methods you need that will store `self.cassette` in some global dict besides calling the super method (again under e.g. `session.config._cassettes`, maybe even make it a mapping of test nodeids to cassette objects?).

Comment: Besides of that, I can imagine using a `requests.Session` (probably via a `pytest` fixture) and accessing the currently cached connections via available connection pool from session adapters, but am not sure whether it is a viable solution at all and its implementation will look clunky for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to comments and guidance in the comments from [@hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling).

I could attach the `cassette` fixture to the `request.node` in a `conftest.py` local plugin overriding the `pytest-vcr` marker...

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _vcr_marker(request):
    marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("vcr")
    if marker:
        cassette = request.getfixturevalue("vcr_cassette")
        vcr = request.getfixturevalue("vcr")
        request.node.__vcr_fixtures = dict(vcr_cassette=cassette, vcr=vcr)
    yield
```

But I needed more than the cassette to get to my solution.

## Ingredients

- Use the [`pytest_exception_interact` hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact)
- Pull request to VCR.py https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy/pull/446

  - [PR #439](https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy/pull/439) and [PR #441](https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy/pull/441) by [`arthurHamon2`](https://github.com/arthurHamon2) has been huge to fix the test suite and also integrate matcher differencing outputs.
- BONUS: Use the [`raise ... from ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752607/622276) form of throwing an exception

## Recipe

### Get latest VCRpy

These patches were released in `vcrpy` v2.1.0

```sh
pip install vcrpy==2.1.0
```

### Override the `pytest_exception_interact` hook

In the root of your test directory create a `conftest.py` to [create a local plugin](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#conftest-py-plugins) that overrides the [`pytest_exception_interact` hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact).

```py
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_exception_interact(node, call, report):
    """Intercept specific exceptions from tests."""
    if report.when == "call" and isinstance(call.excinfo.value, CannotOverwriteExistingCassetteException):
        __handle_cassette_exception(node, call, report)

    yield
```

Extract the `Cassette` and the `Request` from the exception.

```py
# Define new exception to throw
class RequestNotFoundCassetteException(Exception):
   ...

def __handle_cassette_exception(node, call, report):
    # Safely check for attributes attached to exception
    vcr_request = None
    cassette = None
    if hasattr(call.excinfo.value, "cassette"):
        cassette = call.excinfo.value.cassette
    if hasattr(call.excinfo.value, "failed_request"):
        vcr_request = call.excinfo.value.failed_request

    # If we have the extra context available...
    if cassette and vcr_request:

        match_properties = [f.__name__ for f in cassette._match_on]
        this_req, req_str = __format_near_match(cassette.requests, vcr_request, match_properties)

        try:
            raise RequestNotFoundCassetteException(f"{this_req}\n\n{req_str}\n") from call.excinfo.value
        except RequestNotFoundCassetteException as e:
            call.excinfo._excinfo = (type(e), e)
            report.longrepr = node.repr_failure(call.excinfo)
```